# API returning 500 'Internal Server Error' for different parameters

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have an API I'm calling in my webpage 'https://foobar.foo.com/api/complaints/filter'
parameters are like this

```
filter = [
    {
        "Attribute" : "grievance_type_id",
        "Operation" : " = ",
        "Value" : "1"
    }
]
```

when I change the `"Value"` parameter which is the primary key of the `"Attribute"` parameter to a specific numbers, say 9. It returns 500. Why is that happening? It was working just fine for months.

Comment: have you tried sending 9 as a string `'9'` ?

Comment: I am sending it like this "9"

Comment: `500` is a back-end error. So, maybe look at your back-end logs to find the problem..